# Cannot Access Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API with 2 Controllers:  ValuesController and MyController

I initially created ValuesController and I access it using MyUrl/api/values, this works fine.

I then added another controller MyController and in the comments that were generated by Visual Studio, it says that I access it using api/.  When I try api/MyController, it doesn't work, I get a page that reads No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '/api/MyController'.

My WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
```

How do I access the GET in my new controller?  Do I need to modify the WebApiConfig?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the controller-class is actually named "MyController", then the URL that points to it should be:

```
/api/My
```

not:

```
/api/MyController
```